# How to substitute `keras.layers.merge._Merge` in `tensorflow.keras`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to create a custom Merge layer using the `tf.keras` API. However, the new API hides the `keras.layers.merge._Merge` class that I want to inherit from.

The purpose of this is to create a Layer that can perform a weighted sum/merge of the outputs of two different layers. Before, and in `keras` python API (not the one included in `tensorflow.keras`) I could inherit from `keras.layers.merge._Merge` class, which is now not accessible from `tensorflow.keras`.

Where before I could do this

```py
class RandomWeightedAverage(keras.layers.merge._Merge):
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    def _merge_function(self, inputs):
        alpha = K.random_uniform((self.batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])
```

Now I cannot use the same logic if using `tensorflow.keras`

```py
class RandomWeightedAverage(tf.keras.layers.merge._Merge):
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    def _merge_function(self, inputs):
        alpha = K.random_uniform((self.batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])
```

Produces

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v1.keras.layers' has no attribute 'merge'
```

I have also tried inheriting from `Layer` class instead

```py
class RandomWeightedAverage(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    def call(self, inputs):
        alpha = K.random_uniform((self.batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])
```

which gives me a layer with output shape equals to `multiple`, whereas I want the output shape to be well defined. I further attempted

```py
class RandomWeightedAverage(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    def call(self, inputs):
        alpha = K.random_uniform((self.batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]
```

But this did not solve the `multiple` ambiguity as output shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have slightly modified your code to use `tf.random_uniform` instead of `K.random_uniform` and it's working fine on 1.13.1 and 1.14.0 (full snippet and resulting `model.summary()` below).

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)


class RandomWeightedAverage(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        alpha = tf.random_uniform((self.batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]


x1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((32, 32, 1))
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((32, 32, 1))

y = RandomWeightedAverage(4)(inputs=[x1, x2])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=[y])

print(model.summary())
```

[image: model summary]

Comment: Since there are no trainable weights, this can even be done with a simple `Lambda` layer, with a `call(inputs)` function only. Where `alpha = tf.random_uniform(K.shape(inputs)[:1])` and `alpha = K.reshape(alpha, (-1,1,1,1))`

Comment: @DanielMöller correct me if I'm wrong, but that will multiple each sample in the batch by the same random number, instead of producing an unique alpha for each (as intended)

Comment: @Raphael This works very well for a CNN architecture. I was now constructing a DNN where the inputs take the form (input_dim, ), and I changed your code accordingly to `alpha = tf.random_uniform((self.batch_size,1,))` but this reproduces the `multiple` issue in my model, but not on your snippet. Any idea on how to debug?

Comment: @romanovzky could you provide a snippet that reproduces the error? It will help me debug it.

Comment: @romanovzky, no, it multiplieas each sample with a different number. I'm using the batch size of the inputs in the random tensor.

Comment: @RaphaelMeudec I marked this as solved, I haven't looked into this in a while (other tasks took priority) and now with tf2 I'll want to re-write the code.

Comment: @DanielMöller If I understand your code, you are using the shape of the inputs except for the batch-size: `K.shape(inputs)[:1]` drops the batch-size and picks only the shape of a single sample. Therefore, the cast and thereafter the sum will broadcast the same random tensor to each element in the batch

Comment: No, `:1` takes only the batch size as `(batch_size, )`. It's not `1:`